# add a user into collection in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a collection named users and I'm trying to add a user to the collection the code I'm using is

```html
var user1 =  {
  Username: "joonyoftv",
  Password: "joon123",
  Email: "joony@bmail.com",
  Birthday: {
   new Date: ( "2000-08-02")
  },
  FavoriteMovies: [ 61942e53b8d3d951230f0980, 61943aabb8d3d951230f0983 ]
}
```

but i keep on getting an error that says SyntaxError: missing : after property id :
@(shell):6:7
What should i do?

Comment: It is about the JavaScript object you are creating - the `Birthday` field. Also, note that string values are enclosed within single or double quotes.

Comment: Where are you running this query? In the `mongo shell` or some other program?

Comment: @h-sifat im running it in the mongo shell

Answer (score 0):

It's just a simple JavaScript syntax error!

The `new Date: ( "2000-08-02")"` should not be in *curly braces* and ids in `FavoriteMovies` array should be enclosed in string literals.

Object with correct syntax:

```js
var user1 = {
  Username: "joonyoftv",
  Password: "joon123",
  Email: "joony@bmail.com",
  Birthday: new Date("2000-08-02"), // corrected
  FavoriteMovies: ["61942e53b8d3d951230f0980", "61943aabb8d3d951230f0983"],
  //String         ^                        ^  ^                        ^
};
```